# Regex for match comments (everything works, except only a pattern) JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I need to remove all JS ad Html comments (inline + multi line)

So far, I’ve found this:

```
/(\/\*[\w\'\s\r\n\*]*\*\/)|(\/\/[\w\s\']*)|(\<![\-\-\s\w\>\/]*\>)/
```

I could able to match almost every comments but except this kind of comment

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

I’m bit doubt about inside brackets. Any idea about how to efficently achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Posted Answers are really helpful. Foremost Thanks guys. But my use-case Is like finding all sort of comments at once. It seems I need to match this one separately. If there is any possible way like updating my regex it would be great (I’m just a regx beginner ). Content is bit large and lots of iterations are there to run. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex pattern

```
(?=<!--)([\s\S]*?)-->
```

It matches html comments like these:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager (noscript) -->
```

or

```
<!--
multi line 
html comment

-->
```

or

```
<!-- single line html comment -->
```

Test it with https://regex101.com/r/pPnygp/1